# How to custom endpoint using aws-sdk net?

Tags: c#, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net

Does anyone konw how to add custom endpoint using s3 net API??
Detail：https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1283
code Language:C#

the sServiceUrl value="192.168.199.216:7480"

when i call DoesS3BucketExist function,i reviced a Exception（System.UriFormatException）

This is my code

```
public IAmazonS3 CreateClient(string sAccessKeyId, string sAccessKeySecret, string sServiceUrl)
{
    AmazonS3Client s3Client = null;
    try
    {
         AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config();
         config.ServiceURL = sServiceUrl;
         config.UseHttp = false;
         config.SignatureVersion = "v4";
         AWSConfigsS3.UseSignatureVersion4 = true;

         s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(
                        sAccessKeyId,
                        sAccessKeySecret,
                        config
                        );
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         LogHelper.WriteLog("AWS配置", ex, "创建AmazonS3Client失败！");
     }
     return s3Client;
}

public bool DoesBucketExist(string bucketName)
{
    bool bIsExist;
    if (this.Client != null)
    {
        bIsExist = this.Client.DoesS3BucketExist(bucketName);
    }
    else
    {
        bIsExist = false;
    }
    return bIsExist;
}
```

i want to set this property `AWSConfigs.EndpointDefinition = @"c:pathtoendpoints.xml";`,but i don't know how to custom endpoints.json file.

it's so hard to me,maybe i need a god help me!Any Help will appreciated！

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string accessKey = "";
    string secretKey = "";

    AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config()
    {
        ServiceURL = string.Format("http://{0}", "192.168.199.216:7480"),
        UseHttp = true,
        ForcePathStyle = true,
        ProxyHost = "192.168.199.216",
        ProxyPort = 7480
    };

    AWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(creds, config);
 
    ListBucketsResponse response = s3Client.ListBuckets();
    foreach (S3Bucket b in response.Buckets)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", b.BucketName, b.CreationDate);
    } 
}
```